# How to avoid warning : Preparing debugger support of iPAD

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode9-beta

I am using Xcode 9 beta and running on iPAD OS version 10.3.2. But while running Xcode is warning as in attached screenshot. It is loading and loading....[image]

Comment: Devices > Unpairing and restarting does the trick.

Duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46316373/xcode9-iphone-is-busy-preparing-debugger-support-for-iphone

Comment: Check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47448911/1753005

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Same here.. Wait for 20 to 30 minutes and will work !!

Comment: 30 minutes is necessary for me.

Comment: Just go to Window -> Devices and unpair the testing device, then reconnect it and it will work!

Comment: I can confirm that unpairing and reconnecting did accelerate the process down to 1-2 minutes.

Answer (score 10):

restarting the iphone helped me in this case. Now building/running app is normal.

Comment: It could be an answer...The solution worked for him. He did not request clarification or critique...

Comment: This worked for me. It should be an answer not comment!

Answer (score 5):

I waited 5 minutes and it worked! So, just be patient! :)

Answer (score 5):

Tried hard-clean build (command+shift+K) and clean build folder (command+shift+opt+K), then detach and reattach the device worked for me. Not sure why, though.

Comment: cmd-shift-K actually helped the "preparing debugger support" bar start moving for me. Before that nothing was happening at all.

Comment: This did it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this happens after installing a new version of iOS, at least with betas from 11. I just wait a few minutes, as I did previously with the "Processing symbols" status whenever I attached the iPhone after an update.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, for : 
      Preparing debugger support..
i just relaunched Xcode and reattached my device..then i got : 
      Amin is busy .......
and I restarted my IOS and it ask me for verification and done.
hope help you.

Answer (score 0):

I waited for at least 1 hour but nothing happened. Then I restarted my device and again nothing changed. Finally! I restarted my machine and then it took only 5 minutes to get prepared for debugger. And then I was able to test the apps again on real device.

Answer (score 0):

It can just be that iTunes in the background wants to connect to your device.

Answer (score 0):

Close all open background apps. I did it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I think XCode is downloading the DeviceSupport folder for this particular iPhone/OS combination

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it got messed up. Normally it takes 2-15m. But it may stuck on without showing loader.

You can clear Trusted computers and reconnect the device.

**Settings -> Developer -> Clear Trusted Computers**

This process may speed this process.